# Product Version Number in WebAPI Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

How does one add version numbers to a WebAPI Application?

I found a [blog post using a T4 Template](http://vagif.bloggingabout.net/2010/04/24/using-t4-templates-to-manage-assembly-version-information/), but I don't know where to put the template, and where/how to reference it from my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you mentioned uses a separate project. The important step for your problem is step #3.

After adding the template the project must be build. The next step is to delete **AssemblyVersion** and **AssemblyFileVersion** attributes in your **AssemblyInfo.cs**. As the last step you only have to add the generated **.cs** file (using the **Add existing item** dialog).

For a public-facing Web API I would tend to use [attribute routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) for versioning. For other project types, such as class libraries, the solution seems a good one compared to existing approaches.